# AS3 AIR Send email with html content without php

Tags: php, actionscript-3, email, flash, air

I am using [SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27) to send an email with an image.

```
_mailer.sendHTMLMail(
Registry.senderEmail,
Registry.playerEmail,
"Subject",
"<img src='http://www.google.com/images/logo_sm.gif'</img>");
```

It works fine, but I want to send a jpeg picture encoded from the AIR project. Can it be done just using AIR technology?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could send the jpeg as an email attachment via the API's `sendAttachedMail` method vs using the `sendHTMLMail`. `sendAttachedMail ( pFrom:String, pDest:String, pSubject:String, pMess:String, pByteArray:ByteArray, pFileName:String )`

Comment: Yes, I actually did that and it worked out nicely. But I can't get it in the body of the mail. And also, I have a problem with gmail considering that message not coming from the actual sender.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display an image sent together with a mail you need to embed the image as an image with a CID and later reference it via that CID. That is something i don't think SMTPMailer can do right out of the box but it's fairly easy to do anyways.

What you need is CID Embedded Images in a multipart mime message. Google those and you shall find millions of examples built in millions of languages. Might not work with all mail clients. It is less reliable than using images from a server.

ps: Your `<img/>` tag in your example is formatted wrong.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice the bad formatting of the img tag, thanks! I'll look for CID embedding then, and check if it is possible to add it to SMTPMailer. Thank you for the advice!